# No bluetooth adapters found: how to get rid of this error message?

Tags: bluetooth

I am unable to enable bluetooth on my laptop. I am using Ubuntu13.04. I go to 
settings>Hardware>Bluetooth
Then I see what the below screen shot shows:
[image]

I am unable to get rid of this error: No bluetooth adapters found.

I w'd like to add that I have related posts on other 2 sites as given below:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/bluetooth-on-ubuntu13-04-not-functioning-4175473853/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90731/connect-nokia-n73-to-laptop-via-bluetooth?noredirect=1#comment136986_90731

Though it seemed to be a common problem, but I really couldn't get a solution 
in google!! I had been waiting for this issue to get resolved since long.

Comment: What laptop is it? Maybe it has a hardware button to enable/disable bluetooth.

Comment: Are you certain your laptop has Bluetooth hardware?  On mine, it was an option I didn't get, so I have a Bluetooth logo above the keyboard but no actual hardware.

Comment: @schaiba , Mine is Acer laptop. Model: Aspire 5315.  I checked the user manual and nowhere it mentioned regarding bluetooth. No, I am not certain whether it has bluetooth hardware or not. I checked my keyboard but there is no bluetooth logo. Also, the link in my post will give some command outputs. Please see if that can help to troubleshoot. Thank you both of you to look into the matter.

Comment: Thank you @cjm. The problem was known and I could catch the problem because of the question you asked. I called the company and came to know that it doesn't have bluetooth hardware in-built. So, I have purchased it and now my bluetooth is enabled on laptop. Thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is find out if your laptop actually has a Bluetooth adapter.  Not all laptops do, and on some it's an optional feature (so you might have a Bluetooth indicator light, but no actual Bluetooth adapter).  Check your laptop's manual or receipt.  Some manufacturers allow you to look up a laptop by serial number and see its specs.

If there's no Bluetooth adapter, that would explain why Linux can't find any.  Fortunately, they're easy to add as a USB dongle or add-in card.

Comment: Thanks cjm. Just one thing I would like to add here only and not to put a new thread for this: what I found that the downloading speed has increased much after replacing the chord (wire) with bluetooth. Earlier for doing Internet on laptop, I was connecting my laptop with my Nokia N73 via chord. Now when  I replaced the chord with bluetooth (which is very comfortable to use than chord), the downloading speed has increased. Earlier with chord, I was getting 17 kB/s and now I am getting 25 kB/s or more. Is bluetooth better than chord?

Comment: @cjm thanks for the it's/its correction in my other answer. I _hate_ that particular error and keep correcting it in other people's posts only to have someone correct it in mine! :)